# How can we prove that the exponential function shifts an arbitrary non-chaotic differential operator by a constant?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, operator-theory, differential-operators, pseudo-differential-operators

if $f(D)y$ is an arbitrary differential operator, of the basic differential $D \equiv \frac{d}{dx}$, acting on any generic infinitely differentiable function $y(x)$ of some real independent variable $x \in \mathbb{R} $, how can we prove (or disprove) that

$$f(D) e^{ax}y(x) = e^{ax}f(D+a)y(x)$$
$$\therefore f(D+a)y(x) =e^{-ax} f(D) e^{ax}y(x)$$?

Comment: What is the exact specification of $f$? This only properly works if $f$ is a polynomial with constant coefficients, so that $f(D)$ is a linear differential operator with constant coefficients.

Comment: No. $f(D)$ is an arbitrary D-operator. Not just linear, and not just with constant coefficients (i.e. the coefficients may still be functions of $x$),